# Highcharts type flags with custom legend icon

Tags: highcharts

I try to make something like that

[image]

I have a flag and it's legend same text. But it seems custom legend doesn't work with flags. Is it correct?

```
  type: 'flags',
    onSeries: 'resources',
    name: change.get('name'),
    colorByPoint: false,
    shape : 'circlepin',
    width : 16,
    color: '#939598',
    fillColor: '#fff',
    style: {
     color: '#262626'
    },
    data: dataArray,
    marker: {
      symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to override the default function that is creating legend items like that:

```
// legend wrapper
(function (H) {
    H.seriesTypes.flags.prototype.drawLegendSymbol = function (legend, series) {
            var size = legend.itemHeight || 18,
            url = series.userOptions.legendImage || 'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/snow.png';

        series.legendSymbol = this.chart.renderer.image(
            url,
            0,
            0,
            size,
            size
        ).add(series.legendGroup);
    };
})(Highcharts)
```

Later in chart's options set the legend image using custom setting in `flags` series like:

```
legendImage: 'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png',
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mw2fn5td/